# java resultset in jsp page with waterfall table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, pivot, waterfall

I have a basic java program, which fetches records from mysql database and displays in jsp page table.

mysql query:

```
SELECT DATE(op_dt),DATE(req_dt),COUNT(*),SUM(amt_charged) FROM audit_sub WHERE DATE(op_dt)>=? GROUP BY 1,2
```

Note: req_dt will be changed dynamically, according to the input(op_dt).

Query Result:

[image: Query Result]

I have managed to put this table in JSP page. But i want the table to be pivot like the below...

Required Waterfall Table

[image: Required Waterfall Table]

Is it possible? if yes how to do it... any suggestions?

Thanks all :)

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: I have tried to use MultiValuedHashMap but dosnt seem to get the correct logic.. if you have any suggestions, you're welcome!